# get different branch file on github

Tags: git, github, git-branch

I have to repository on my GitHub.
master and beta.

I created beta because I want to experiment some changes without changing the stable version that is currently on the master.
I already push the changes on the beta branches but I don't want to finalize it so all the pushes since then is on the beta branch.

Now, I want to pull my master version and completely override my files.
Since I have the copy of the latest files on my beta branch, I want to change my source files to master branch.

Is it possible to do this?
If I want to go back to beta branch, what will i do too?

Comment: Do you want to change all files in beta branch to what is present in the master branch?

Comment: No I dont want that. I want to keep my beta brach unchange and Use my master branch files

Comment: There are two ways, you can checkout the master branch `git checkout master` or create a new branch with files from master using `git checkout -b master-new master`.